# Why does the jQuery file upload stop working after first upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm using the [jQuery File Upload plugin](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/). I'm hiding the file input and activating it upon clicking a separate button. (See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lolson/xSAQN/).)

HTML:

```
<div>
    <button class="browse">Browse</button>
    <input id="upload" type="file" style="display: none;" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var element = $("#upload");

$(".browse").click(function () {
    $("#upload").trigger("click");
});

element.fileupload({
    add: function () {
        alert("add");
    }
});
```

Notice that if you press the button then select a file, the `add` method is activated and you'll get an alert. Do it again, and you'll get another alert.

Now, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lolson/xSAQN/8/). The only difference is that I've changed the following line

```
$("#upload").trigger("click");
```

to

```
element.trigger("click");
```

Notice that now, the first time you click the button then select a file, the `add` method is activated and you get the alert (just like before), but if you do it again, the `add` method never activates.

What is causing this difference in behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks as though the scope of `element` is being lost / changed after the add function.  Resetting it like below seems to work.

```
var element = $("#upload");

$(".browse").click(function () {
    element.trigger("click");
});

element.fileupload({
    add: function () {
        alert("add");
        element = $(this);
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xSAQN/12/)

Comment: Brilliant. So strange that it's getting changed somehow.

Comment: Thats what i did in my first example, this seems great with your code.

Comment: Note that when i tried this i had to also call `data.submit()` in 'add' for it to proceed, as seen here: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#callbacks

Answer (score 9):

This can also be solved by setting `replaceFileInput` to `false`, as stated by the [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#replacefileinput). This is because the plugin recreates the input element after each upload, and so events bound to the original input will be lost.

Comment: Good answer, but i would recommend everyone to read the documentation and linked FAQ first, as thats set default 'true' for a reason. In my case as well as the OP, using the 'add' workaround seem a better solution.

Comment: Great. Solved the problem for me

Answer (score 3):

Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/xSAQN/6/

```
var input = $("#upload");

$(".browse").click(function () {
    input.trigger("click", uploadit(input));
});

function uploadit(input){
    $(input).fileupload({
        add: function () {
            alert("add");
        }
    });
}
```

Although there is one more way:

just change to this:

```
   var element = $("#upload");

   $(".browse").click(function () {
       $("#upload").click(); // <----trigger the click this way
   });

   element.fileupload({
      add: function () {
          alert("add");
      }
   });
```

Comment: Hmmm... Interesting. Why do I have to re-initialize the plugin every time it's clicked? It works in the first example above and I'm not doing that...

Comment: Um... Isn't the second way exactly what I have posted above in my first example?